# How to keep smaller value in front in a 3d bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This question is related to question [How do I keep the smaller value in a bar chart in front (when I cannot place the bars side by side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749833/how-do-i-keep-the-smaller-value-in-a-bar-chart-in-front-when-i-cannot-place-the)

I want to do such thing in 3d plot. Although the masks looks ok, plot only displays higher values. I cannot understand why this code is not plotting bars that would not cover each other. Each step (ax.bar) looks good, but combined together only higher value is shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

dim1 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
dim2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
var1 = np.array([1, 2, 1.5, 1.25])
var2 = np.array([0.5, 2.2, 1.15, 1.75])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

mask_var1 = ma.where(var1>=var2)
mask_var2 = ma.where(var2>=var1)

print mask_var1
print mask_var2

# Draw var1 bar where var1 >= var2
ax.bar(dim1[mask_var1], var1[mask_var1], dim2[mask_var1], zdir='y', width=0.1, color='red')
# Draw var2
ax.bar(dim1, var2, dim2, zdir='y', width=0.1, color='blue')
# Draw var1 bar where var2 >= var1
ax.bar(dim1[mask_var2], var1[mask_var2], dim2[mask_var2], zdir='y', width=0.1, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Axes3D` has [problems](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles) layering patches in this way. You may compute and plot only the visible parts of each patch.

```
# Draw var1 bar where var1 >= var2
ax.bar(dim1[mask_var1], (var1 - var2)[mask_var1], dim2[mask_var1],
       bottom=var2[mask_var1], zdir='y', width=0.1, color='red')

# Draw var2 bar where var2 >= var1
ax.bar(dim1[mask_var2], (var2 - var1)[mask_var2], dim2[mask_var2],
       bottom=var1[mask_var2], zdir='y', width=0.1, color='blue')

# Draw var1 bar where var2 >= var1
ax.bar(dim1[mask_var2], var1[mask_var2], dim2[mask_var2], zdir='y',
       width=0.1, color='red')

# Draw var2 bar where var1 >= var2
ax.bar(dim1[mask_var1], var2[mask_var1], dim2[mask_var1], zdir='y',
       width=0.1, color='blue')
```

[image]